# Electron AJAX request return raw PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, electron, responsetext

I'm developing a kiosk application with Electron. Currently, I'm stuck with making an AJAX request to the server with a native Javascript code (**no JQuery**). Every time I made an AJAX request, it always returned the raw PHP code. Here is my project directory:

```
SelfService
|- script
   |- login.js
|- lib
   |- userAuth.php
|- node_modules
|- index.html
|- index.js
|- package.json
|- package-lock.json
```

In my javascript, I have tried to set the "Content-Type" to "application/json", or following another example of AJAX request on the net, set it to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" before sending the XMLHttpRequest, but both of them still returned the raw PHP code.

As for the server side, I have already set the header as "Content-Type: application/json" and use json_encode for the result.

On the side note: I installed the Electron on different drive than my web server. I installed WAMP on default location `(C:\wamp)` while I installed the Electron on `D:` Drive (I wondered if that actually matters)

index.html:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input_id" value="" />
    <button onclick="authenticateID();">Click to authenticate ID</button>
    <div id="response"></div>
</body>
```

/script/login.js:

```
function authenticateID () {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'lib/userAuth.php'
    var params = 'id=' + document.getElementById('input_id').value;

    xhr.open('POST', url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
//    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            var xhrResult = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

            var responseContainer = document.getElementById(response);
            responseContainer.innerHTML = xhrResult.isValidID;
        }
    }

    xhr.onerror = function () { alert('Something went wrong') }
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

/lib/userAuth.php:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$result['isValidID'] = (!empty($_POST['id'])) ? '1' : '0';
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

If the user typed in the ID in the textbox, I expect the output will be either "1" or "0", but when I show the xhr.responseText with `alert(xhr.responseText)`, it returned the whole raw PHP code of `lib/userAuth.php`

**EDIT:** Now that's a huge mistake I made. I though Electron has some kind of built-in web servers that can process PHP file, so I put my PHP file in the project folder, which is in a different location from the web server. Now I have separated the PHP script into the web server, how am I supposed to set the URL in `var url = 'lib/userAuth.php'`? I tried `localhost/SelfService/lib/userAuth.php` but in error log, it says `ERR:FILE_NOT_FOUND`

Comment: The problem is most likely a mistake in your WAMP configuration. It seems that PHP is not activated there.

Comment: are you sure your PHP file reside on your local server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason server is returning PHP code is that your server is not configured properly. Check if your server files resides in localhost server folder.

Comment: I'm kinda new to Electron, and like I mentioned above, I put my project folder in ```D:``` drive, different location from the web server (in ```C:``` drive). So does that mean I need to separate my PHP file, which originally in my project folder into the web server in ```C:```?

Comment: Technically "Yes", Think like this. you only need to make ajax request to server for fetching data. So, for example: if your server is running on "localhost:8080/some-url". Just make the request to the endpoint from your electron application. Don`t forget to enable CORS on your server. Your elector code can reside anywhere u want.